# Pass an Action<T> to a generic method via reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates, action

I know there's similar questions to this but I still wasn't able to resolve my issue.

I have a `EventManager` static class, which is just a wrapper for `EventManagerInternal`, like so:

```
public static class EventManager
{
    public static void Subscribe<T>(Action<T> handler) where T : GameEvent
    {
        EventManagerInternal<T>.Subscribe(handler);
    }
    public static void Unsubscribe<T>(Action<T> handler) where T : GameEvent
    {
        EventManagerInternal<T>.Unsubscribe(handler);
    }
    public static void Raise<T>(T e) where T : GameEvent
    {
        EventManagerInternal<T>.Raise(e);
    }

    private static class EventManagerInternal<T> where T : GameEvent
    {
        private static Dictionary<Type, Action<T>> dic = new Dictionary<Type, Action<T>>();
        public static void Subscribe(Action<T> handler)
        {
            // sub code...
        }
        public static void Unsubscribe(Action<T> handler)
        {
            // unsub code...
        }
        public static void Raise(T e)
        {
            // raise code...
        }
    }
}
```

**Example usage:**

```
public class OnRename : GameEvent { }

public void OnRenameHandler(OnRename e) { }

EventManager.Subscribe<OnRename>(OnRenameHandler); // <-- the statement that I wanna generate via reflection
```

My question is: I want to generate the same thing (same usage example like ^) via reflection but I'm unable to. How to do it?

I managed to get the subscribe method right:

```
MethodInfo subscribe = typeof(EventManager).GetMethod("Subscribe").MakeGeneric(typeof(GameEvent)); // right?
```

But then how to invoke it passing in `OnRenameHandler`?

Knowing that I have a `MethodInfo` to `OnRenameHandler`

```
MethodInfo handler = typeof(SomeType).GetMethod("OnRenameHandler");

subscribe.Invoke(null, WHAT_TO_PASS_HERE?);
```

I tried `Delegate.CreateDelegate` but didn't get anywhere, I'm not sure it's the solution.

I've looked at several links, tried several things, but none worked.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: In first place why reflection?

Comment: Well, there's some details about why I would wanna use it which I didn't wanna mention cause I felt they're not relevant. I'm using Unity3D and working on system where you could specify a target gameObject to get notified of a certain event. I use reflection to get all the methods in all the MonoBehaviours in the GO to see if there's a handler that matches a certain signature, if so, I take that handler (which is a method info for now) and have it subscribe to the event I want. `EvMan.Sub<OnSomthng>(handler);` everything is done via reflection that is why I need that call to be dynamic.

Comment: should be `MakeGeneric(typeof(OnRename))`, no? And then pass in `new Action<OnRename>(OnRenameHandler)`.

Comment: @leppie thanks. yeah well that works, but I'm not gonna have a direct reference to `OnRenameHandler` - instead, I have a `MethodInfo` of it. And... can't I generate the `Action` dynamically? without having to specify `<OnRename>`? something like `CreateAction(typeof(OnRename));`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`Delegate.CreateDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.createdelegate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) static method to create delegate with a type known at runtime. First parameter sets the delegate type.

```
// get subscribe method info
var subscribe = typeof(EventManager).GetMethod("Subscribe")
                                    .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(OnRename));

// prepare delegate instance
var delegateType = typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(OnRename));
var methodInfo = typeof(TypeWithOnRenameHandlerMethod).GetMethod("OnRenameHandler");
var del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, this, methodInfo);

// invoke subscribe method
subscribe.Invoke(null, new [] { del });
```

Replace `this` as second `Delegate.CreateDelegate` parameter if you need to call the method on other then current instance.

PS. I assumed that you really need to call `Subscribe<OnRename>`, not `Subscribe<GameEvent>`. Feel free to change it back if I'm wrong.

Comment: EXACTLY what I'm looking for! +10000 Awesome!! me luv SOF :D